# Set the CSS of a table row

Tags: jquery, css

Thought this would be easy, but i'm having trouble!

I have a table and when I search for a row within that table based on a name I want to highlight the row that it has found. I am trying the following code:

```
    var elem = $("#table-names tr:contains("+ name +")");
    $(elem).css("background-color", "red");
```

But it isnt working.

Edit (html below):

```
    <table id="table-names" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Pos</th>
                <th align="center">Name</th>
                <th align="center">Points</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <?php 
                $rows = getPoints(); 
                foreach ($rows->body as $row):
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $row->position; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row->teamshort; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row->points; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <? endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Am I missing something?

Cheers

Comment: provide relevant HTML markup otherwise it's quite impossible to help

Comment: BTW, no need to rewrap elem inside jquery object

Comment: do you see the markup now? Took me a while to pretty print it :-)

Comment: I see useless PHP code, not rendered HTML. And we still don't know which name has as value...  Here you see that your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Uad3P/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text inside the parentheses of `:contains()` needs to be surrounded by quotation marks.

It should be

```
var elem = $("#table-names tr:contains('"+ name +"')");
```

[More information here.](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: it depends of value of name, but that seems fair enough

Comment: that didnt make a difference to be honest, but noted for future